# How can I make a horizontal dashed line?

Tags: formatting, rules

How can I make a horizontal dashed line in LaTeX?

Just writing lots of single dashes results in a continuous horizontal line.

Answer (score 39):

You can look at the [`dashrule`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dashrule) package, for example.

Comment: Nice... a lot of flexibility :)

Comment: It would also be great if this answer included a simple example of how to use `dashrule`.

Answer (score 16):

With Plain leaders, for example:

```
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox{-}\hfill}
\hbox to \hsize{\dashfill\hfil}
\bye
```

Changing the spacing is then a matter of redefining the dashfill's hbox:

```
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to 2em{-}\hfill}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about adding spaces between the dashes:  `- - - - - -` ? When I try it, it works just fine. Or do you want something else?