# Can a table include a horizontal dashed line?

Tags: tables, formatting, rules

In a normal table, you can use the `\hline` command to draw a horizontal line. I am trying to make this line a dashed horizontal line.

I have found the package `dashrule` [via this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line), but this only works for `\rule` situations; i.e. it can't be directly used as a line in a table, and LaTeX won't compile it. Conversely, I've tried wrapping the `\hdashrule` in a multicolumn:

```
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\hdashrule{130mm}{1pt}{4pt}} \
```

However, the padding around the table cell breaks the flow of the table, and the horizontal rule is not aligned with the other `\hline`s of the table. (It also means that the rule width must be specified manually.)

Is there any way to make a `\hline` dashed without resorting to tables-in-tables? Can you force a single table cell to have no vertical or horizontal margins and padding?

Comment: Maybe you can help on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171518/how-to-create-vertical-and-horizontal-dotted-lines-in-a-matrix?

Comment: Does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629520/38244 (2nd solution)

Answer (score 123):

The [arydshln](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arydshln) package offers you the `\hdashline` and `\cdashline` commands which are the dashed counterparts of `\hline` and `\cline`, respectively. A little example (including also a vertical dashed line):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c:cc}
   column1a & column2a & column3a \\
   column1b & column2b   & column3b\\ \hdashline
   column1c & column2c & column3c \\ \cdashline{1-2}
   column1d & column2d & column3d \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also specify how wide the dashes should be by specifying a ratio. For a dotted line write

```
\hdashline[0.5pt/5pt]
```

Comment: It seems like that \usepackage{arydshln} is not compatible with 
\usepackage{tabularx}. They cannot coexist. Is there any resolution for this?

Comment: Maybe you can help on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171518/how-to-create-vertical-and-horizontal-dotted-lines-in-a-matrix?

Comment: spacing never comes our right when I use `\hdashline`, not sure what the deal is.

Comment: @wonderich At least just having both packages loaded doesn't seem to cause any problems (in 2022)

Comment: Note that `\usepackage{arydshln}` also breaks in-table colouring with `\colour{}{}`

Comment: `arydshln` also conflicts with `longtable`

Comment: @user35443 I had the same problem. What worked for me was calling `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and *then* `\usepackage{arydshln}`, and to colour a table cell use `\cellcolor`.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution for dash lines with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{c|[dashed]cc}
   column1a & column2a & column3a \\
   column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\hline[dashed]
   column1c & column2c & column3c \\
\cline[dashed]{1-2}
   column1d & column2d & column3d \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the package `nicematrix`, you can create tools which will draw rules in your environment `{NiceTabular}` (of `nicematrix`) with Tikz: all the styles of Tikz may be used...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = : ,
       command = dashedline , 
       ccommand = cdashedline ,
       tikz = dashed
     }
  }

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c:cc}
   column1a & column2a & column3a \\
   column1b & column2b & column3b \\
\dashedline
   column1c & column2c & column3c \\
\cdashedline{1-2}
   column1d & column2d & column3d \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]