# How to create a dashed line in tabularx environment

Tags: tables, rules, tabularx

I've been looking into this, and I have encountered two main "solutions":

```
\usepackage{arydshln}
```

As decribed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20141/27833).

And this one:

```
\usepackage{dashrule}
```

As described in [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12537/27833).

However, since I'm loading these packages:

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepaclage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
```

It seems I can't use neither `arydshln` nor `dashline`.

Any idea why this is happening?  How can I get a dashed horizontal line inside my `tabularx` which is **at the same time-** inside a `table` environment?

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}


\begin{document}
Hello.

\begin{longtabu}{l p{0.8\linewidth}}
WHO                 &   \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\[1mm]
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\[1mm]
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\[1mm]

\end{longtabu}

\begin{table}\tiny
    \caption{Muscles of the thigh}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYYYY}
        Muscle & Origin & Insertion& Nerve & Action \\
        \firsthline\\
            \textbf{Anterior Compartment}   & & &   &   \\[3mm]

            Quadriceps femoris                                                                                          &
            Rectus Femoris: anterior inferior iliac spine. Vastus Lateralis: greater trochanter and linea aspera of femur. Vastus Intermedius: body of femur.  Vastus Medialis: linea aspera of femur                &
            Patella and onto tibial tuberosity through patellar ligament        &
            Femoral                                                                                                                 &
            Extends knee; rectus femoris also flexes hip\\\\

            Sartorius                                                                                                               &
            Anterior superiro iliac spine                                                                       &
            Medial side of tibial tuberosity                                                                &
            Femoral                                                                                                                 &
            Flexes hip and knee; rotates thigh laterally and leg medially\\\\

            \hline\\% I want this line to be dashed
            \textbf{Medial Compartment} & & &   &   \\[3mm]

            Adductor brevis                                                                                                 &
            Pubis                                                                                                                       &
            Pectineal line and linea aspera of femur                                                &
            Obturator                                                                                                               &
            Adducts, laterally rotates thigh; flexes hip\\\\

            Adductor longus                                                                                                 &
            Pubis                                                                                                                       &
            Linea aspera of femur                                                                                       &
            Obturator                                                                                                               &
            Adducts, laterally rotates thigh; flexes hip\\\\

            \lasthline\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:ThighMuscles2}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Now, if I use `\dashrule` where the `\hline` is (after loading the `dashrule` package, of course), I get an *Undefined control sequence* error.

If I use the `\hdashline` (of the `arydshln` package) I get 101 errors which point me to other tables in my document, so I'm guessing it has something to do with incompatibility with the other packages I loaded.

Comment: Please post a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: Please, an example should always start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` so that other people can run it, and shows which packages you have loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, since I created my own style for my thesis... so I'm loading a lot of packages.  Should I include only the "relevant" information?

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225) But basically anyone trying to help you is going to need a document using `article` class that includes that table and that uses no packages that are not relevant to the question. So you should make one.

Comment: Got it, editing right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

It worked for me without error, if it doesn't work for you you need to make an example that shows the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
Hello.

\begin{table}\tiny
    \caption{Muscles of the thigh}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYYYY}
        Muscle & Origin & Insertion& Nerve & Action \\
        \firsthline\\
            \textbf{Anterior Compartment}   & & &   &   \\[3mm]

            Quadriceps femoris                                                                                          &
            Rectus Femoris: anterior inferior iliac spine. Vastus Lateralis: greater trochanter and linea aspera of femur. Vastus Intermedius: body of femur.  Vastus Medialis: linea aspera of femur                &
            Patella and onto tibial tuberosity through patellar ligament        &
            Femoral                                                                                                                 &
            Extends knee; rectus femoris also flexes hip\\\\

            Sartorius                                                                                                               &
            Anterior superiro iliac spine                                                                       &
            Medial side of tibial tuberosity                                                                &
            Femoral                                                                                                                 &
            Flexes hip and knee; rotates thigh laterally and leg medially\\\\

            \hdashline\\% I want this line to be dashed
            \textbf{Medial Compartment} & & &   &   \\[3mm]

            Adductor brevis                                                                                                 &
            Pubis                                                                                                                       &
            Pectineal line and linea aspera of femur                                                &
            Obturator                                                                                                               &
            Adducts, laterally rotates thigh; flexes hip\\\\

            Adductor longus                                                                                                 &
            Pubis                                                                                                                       &
            Linea aspera of femur                                                                                       &
            Obturator                                                                                                               &
            Adducts, laterally rotates thigh; flexes hip\\\\

            \lasthline\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:ThighMuscles2}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

With the updated example using `longtabu` It works if you change `longtabu` to `longtable` The `tabu` package has some nice ideas but unfortunately it incorrectly defines the standard latex array package `>{..}` syntax (This is an intentional, documented feature of the package, not a bug as such) and has other incompatibilities, so often you need to go "the tabu way" and just use the features of that package or use a combination of packages that *are* designed to cooperate and not clash when used at the same time.

Comment: I got what causes the error! I know I shouldn't be happy (since I haven't found a solution), but at least now I know how to replicate it: It happens when you use one of these tables with the `longtable` environment along in the same project.  I'm not sure why.  I'll edit my post to show how this happens when both tables are used.

Comment: @MarioS.E. This is why we always ask people to put a complete example _that shows the problem_

Comment: I know, I'm very sorry; but it was also very difficult for me to actually find it.  As you can imagine, my work at this point is full of tables, and I had no clue where to start.  I just had a hunch to start commenting all the "tabu"'s.  @Jon pointed my out a few hours ago that the author of `tabu` is building a new version that is not going to be backwards compatible, so I panicked and start changing everything.

Comment: I added some notes re tabu

Comment: As the arydshln package will also have issues with hyperref, the easiest for a layout as the above is to define the dash line with xleaders and be done with it?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides does it? (why are they clashing:-) Yes it is true that horizontal leaders are fairly easy anyway the more interesting part of `arydshln` is getting vertical dashed lines which are trickier.

Comment: Not too sure why---I didn't check it, but is in the hyperef hot list. Correct loading order is

    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepacakge{hyperref}
    \usepackage{arydshln}

Comment: How do I do this with xleaders?

Comment: Maybe you can help on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171518/how-to-create-vertical-and-horizontal-dotted-lines-in-a-matrix?