# Dashed hline in longtabu (arydshln conflicts, does not work?)

Tags: tables, longtable, incompatibility, tabu, arydshln

I have a large table with the following requirements:

- Spans multiple pages (currently using `longtable`)
- The last column's text must wrap (using `tabu`'s `longtabu` environment as `tabularx` does not support multiple pages)

I am trying to add dashed horizontal lines like `arydshln`'s `\hdashline`.
The [`arydshln` documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/arydshln/arydshln.pdf) indicates that some care must be taken when loading with `longtable`, but even when it is loaded after the table packages, it still will not compile. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106511/how-to-create-a-dashed-line-in-tabularx-environment) indicates that the `arydshln` package apparently conflicts with `tabu`, but doesn't solve the problem as their table is only one page and can thus be switched to `tabularx`.

How can I can I create dashed lines in a multi-page table with one column whose text wraps?

A smaller MWE is here, the lipsum paragraphs are a bit longer than realistic, but get the point across:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[layout=letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {c c l X}
\rowfont\bfseries Prefix & Address & Data Field & Description \\ \hline
\endhead
\tt 1000 & \tt 0000 & 32-bit Data & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0001 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0010 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0011 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0100 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0101 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 1XX0 & 32-bit Data & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\hline % <--- Would like this to be dashed
\tt 1010 & \tt 1000 & 32-bit DMA Data & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1010 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1011 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1100 & DMA Control Message$\dagger$ & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1100 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\hline % <--- Would like this to be dashed
\tt 1011 & \tt 0010 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\tabucline[<options>]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[layout=letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {c c l X}
\rowfont\bfseries Prefix & Address & Data Field & Description \\ \hline
\endhead
\tt 1000 & \tt 0000 & 32-bit Data & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0001 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0010 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0011 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0100 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 0101 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1000 & \tt 1XX0 & 32-bit Data & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\tabucline[1pt on 3pt]
\tt 1010 & \tt 1000 & 32-bit DMA Data & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1010 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1011 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1100 & DMA Control Message$\dagger$ & \small\lipsum[1] \\
\tt 1010 & \tt 1100 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\tabucline[1pt on 3pt]
\tt 1011 & \tt 0010 & 32-bit Data & ... \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The tabu manual says: "`\tabucline` does not care of page breaks presently: use `\hline` instead." Is there an alternative to using `\tabucline`? [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182778/18520) is an example showing an issue with `\tabucline` and page breaking.

Comment: @sergej feel free to open a new question.

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182778/18520) is the question.