# Longtabu, \tabucline placed on wrong page

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, tabu

See the following `longtabu` axample:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=1.5mm    % <---- seems like this is causing the issue

\def\head{Head A & Head B}
\def\nbcolumns{2}
\begin{longtabu}{X[.5,l] X[1,l]}
  \toprule\rowfont{\bfseries}
  \head\\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
%
  \multicolumn{\nbcolumns}{l}{\scriptsize\itshape\ldots Fortsetzung}\\
  \toprule\rowfont{\bfseries}
  \head\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
%
  \multicolumn{\nbcolumns}{r}{\scriptsize\itshape wird fortgesetzt \ldots}
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
%
  \everyrow{\tabucline[on 3 pt off 3pt]-}
  1 & \lipsum[2] \\
  2 & \lipsum[2] \\
  3 & \lipsum[2] \\
  4 & \lipsum[2] \\
  5 & \lipsum[2] \\
  6 & \lipsum[2] \\
  7 & \lipsum[2] \\
  8 & \lipsum[2] 
  \everyrow{}\\
  \bottomrule
  \caption{Table name}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

... and the resulting document:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The page break from page 1 to page 2 is as expected.

But there is an issue with the page break from page 2 to page 3. The first dashed line on the top of page 3 should be placed on the bottom of page 2.

How can I fix it?

Or should I consider using an alternative to `longtabu`?

Comment: You could consider replacing the dashed rules with a little bit of white space.

Comment: @Thruston I am sorry, but I am afraid I can't follow you. Do you have an example? I like the dashed rules, but one of the rules is placed on the wrong page.

Comment: I was suggesting that you could easily avoid your problem by not using the rules at all.  Personally I think tables look better with as few rules as possible.  But if you like them that's fine too!

Comment: The documentation of `tabu` says "\tabucline does not care of page breaks presently: use \hline instead."

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank's for your answer, can I modify `\hline` to be dashed?

Comment: I don't see that this can be done easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can add a `\nobreak` so linebreaking before the tabu cline is discouraged and add a `\filbreak` so linebreaking (and padding with space) after the line is encouraged.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\tabucline{\noalign{\nobreak\ifnum0=`}\fi \tabu@cline}


\def\tabu@docline@evr {\xdef\tabu@doclineafter{\the\toks@\filbreak}%
              \ifnum0=`{\fi}\aftergroup\tabu@doclineafter}

\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=1.5mm    % <---- seems like this is causing the issue

\def\head{Head A & Head B}
\def\nbcolumns{2}
\begin{longtabu}{X[.5,l] X[1,l]}
  \toprule\rowfont{\bfseries}
  \head\\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
%
  \multicolumn{\nbcolumns}{l}{\scriptsize\itshape\ldots Fortsetzung}\\
  \toprule\rowfont{\bfseries}
  \head\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
%
  \multicolumn{\nbcolumns}{r}{\scriptsize\itshape wird fortgesetzt \ldots}
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
%
  \everyrow{\tabucline[on 3 pt off 3pt]-}
  1 & \lipsum[2] \\
  2 & \lipsum[2] \\
  3 & \lipsum[2] \\
  4 & \lipsum[2] \\
  5 & \lipsum[2] \\
  6 & \lipsum[2] \\
  7 & \lipsum[2] \\
  8 & \lipsum[2]
  \everyrow{}\\*
  \bottomrule
  \caption{Table name}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```