# Dotfill in a matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to ask if you know how to make a row entirely filled by dots in a matrix? I tried to use the `\dotfill` but it isn't proper because it hasn't changed anything, everything is the same after typing this command. Of course, I can do something like that: `\hdots&\hdots&...` . But in the part of the book I'm rewriting in LaTeX there is a row of dots in the matrix.

Comment: Related: [How to create vertical and horizontal dotted lines in a matrix?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171518/5764); [Can a table include a horizontal dashed line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20140/5764)

Comment: Beside  solution in given links there is also `amsmath` macro `\hdotsfor[<spacing factor>]{<number of columns>}`. Described is for example in manual `mathmode.pdf` written by Herbert Woss. It is worth to read!

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Everybody should be grateful for everything :). My colleague tried the same solution. But this doesn't work properly. I tried typing the command \hdotsfor[<number>] and, as a result, in the output pdflatex gave me only one dot.

Comment: OK, I used [<number>] instead of {<number>} but it also doesn't work properly. The "lines" on the left side of the matrix and these on the right side of it are partially getting blind.