# Internal delimiters for matrix and array

Tags: matrices, arrays, delimiters, bigdelim

I would like to customize the array environment in such a way that I can write arrays with dashed delimiters that are internal to the arrays as in the figure below.

[image]

> **Question.** *How do I place the vertical and horizontal delimiters on the inside of the arrays? Is it possible to have control over the customization of the delimiters? Like can I control the delimiters so that they are dashed or continuous or colored?*

Thanks in advance.

**My attempt.** The best I got was using the code below.

```
    \begin{center}
    \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c}
    \underline{\displaystyle{A}_{\vspace{5mm}}} 
    & 
    \underline{\displaystyle{B}_{\vspace{5mm}}} 
    & 
    \underline{\displaystyle{E}_{\vspace{5mm}}} 
    \\ 
    \underline{\displaystyle{C}_{\vspace{5mm}}}
    & 
    \underline{\displaystyle{D}_{\vspace{5mm}}}
    & 
    \underline{\displaystyle{F}_{\vspace{5mm}}}
    \\
    \underline{\displaystyle{G}_{\vspace{5mm}}}
    &
    \underline{\displaystyle{H}_{\vspace{5mm}}}
    & 
    \underline{\displaystyle{L}_{\vspace{5mm}}}
    \end{array}\right]
    \end{center}
```

And the result was somewhat unsatisfactory as can be seen in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `arydshln` package.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20141

Comment: @antshar Yes+1. Answer my question. It helped a lot. But is there an alternative without using the "arydshln" package?

Comment: @MathOverview: With `nicematrix` you can do that with dotted lines. And you can use both `nicematrix` and `arydshln`.

Answer (score 2):

As from suggestion of the creator `F. Pantigny` of `nicematrix` package, I add the differents output considering also the comments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\[\left[\,\begin{NiceArray}{c:c:c}
A & B & C  \\
\hdashline
D & E & F \\
\hdashline
G & H & O
\end{NiceArray}\,\right]
\]

\[\left[\,\begin{NiceArray}{c:c}
A & B   \\
\hdashline
D & E  \\
\end{NiceArray}\,\right]
\]

\[\left[\,\begin{NiceArray}{c}
A  \\
\hdashline
D   \\
\end{NiceArray}\,\right]
\]


\[\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c:c}
A  & V\\
\end{NiceArray}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]