# Pattern for \vrule

Tags: macros

Is it possible to apply patterns to \vrule like dotted?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\le\le=50pt
\def\A{\vrule depth0pt height 50pt width 1 \le}

\begin{document}
\A
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line

Comment: do you want a horizontal or vertical row of dots? (your example shows vrule which starts a new paragraph and enters horizontal mode)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Doesn't matter.

Comment: @RicardoCristianRamirez well the answers are rather different, either way you need \leaders for horizontal dashes there is an answer in the linked question (vertical version is similarchanging v/h appropriately)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not too clear to me, which kind of dotted lines/areas are to be set.
The following example generates a dotted area using `\leaders` (also `\cleaders` can be used):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\le\le=50pt

\newcommand*{\A}{%
  \leavevmode
  \leaders\vbox{%
    \leaders\vbox{%
      \kern.5\fontdimen3\font
      \hbox{.}%
      \kern.5\fontdimen3\font
    }\vskip50pt %
  }\hskip\le\null
}

\begin{document}
\A
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

More about `\leaders` can be found in chapter 9 "Rules and Leaders" of ["TeX by Topic"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) by Victor Eijkhout.