# how to draw a cut through a graph in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, technical-drawing, tkz-graph

I want to draw a cut through the graph, like a line passing through the edges from the `source` to `gamma`, `source` to `alpha` and `source` to `omega`. I am doing that to demonstrate a minimum cut in a network ((Algorithm analysis ))

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}

  \node (s) at (0,5){source};
  \node (v1) at (5,9){alpha};
  \node (v4) at (13,9){beta};
  \node (v2) at (5,1){omega};
  \node (v3) at (6,5){gamma};
  \node (v5) at (13,1){theta};
  \node (v6) at (16,5){delta};
  \node (t) at (20,5){sink};

\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
\Edge[label=$1/1$](s)(v1);
\Edge[label=$4/4$](s)(v2);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](s)(v3);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v2)(v4);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v2)(v5);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v1)(v4);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v3)(v4);
\Edge[label=$4/4$](v6)(t);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v5)(t);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v4)(t);
\Edge[label=$1/4$](v5)(v6);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v3)(v6);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v4)(v6);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to provide a *complete* minimum working example (MWE), beginning with `\documentclass` and showing all the packages and options you are using.  Think of the time it will save those trying to help you.  Help us help you.

Comment: I'm sure others will know but I, at least, have no idea how to get that to compile. Which package defines `\Edge`?

Answer (score 6):

Using the calc library you can say something like

```
\draw[dashed] 
  ([yshift=60pt]$ (s)!0.5!(v1) $ ) -- 
  ([yshift=-60pt]$ (s)!0.5!(v2) $ );
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}

  \node (s) at (0,5){source};
  \node (v1) at (5,9){alpha};
  \node (v4) at (13,9){beta};
  \node (v2) at (5,1){omega};
  \node (v3) at (6,5){gamma};
  \node (v5) at (13,1){theta};
  \node (v6) at (16,5){delta};
  \node (t) at (20,5){sink};

\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
\Edge[label=$1/1$](s)(v1);
\Edge[label=$4/4$](s)(v2);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](s)(v3);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v2)(v4);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v2)(v5);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v1)(v4);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v3)(v4);
\Edge[label=$4/4$](v6)(t);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v5)(t);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v4)(t);
\Edge[label=$1/4$](v5)(v6);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v3)(v6);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v4)(v6);

\draw[dashed] 
  ([yshift=60pt]$ (s)!0.5!(v1) $ ) -- 
  ([yshift=-60pt]$ (s)!0.5!(v2) $ );

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't work give me errors

Comment: @bebo You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept answers that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to their left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 1):

One can add the cuts externally to the picture after the fact with `\stackinset`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
% DASHED LINE OF SPECIFIED LENGTH
% From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
% how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .6em{-}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\mygraph}{\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
  \node (s) at (0,5){source};
  \node (v1) at (5,9){alpha};
  \node (v4) at (13,9){beta};
  \node (v2) at (5,1){omega};
  \node (v3) at (6,5){gamma};
  \node (v5) at (13,1){theta};
  \node (v6) at (16,5){delta};
  \node (t) at (20,5){sink};
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
\Edge[label=$1/1$](s)(v1);
\Edge[label=$4/4$](s)(v2);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](s)(v3);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v2)(v4);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v2)(v5);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v1)(v4);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v3)(v4);
\Edge[label=$4/4$](v6)(t);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v5)(t);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v4)(t);
\Edge[label=$1/4$](v5)(v6);
\Edge[label=$1/1$](v3)(v6);
\Edge[label=$2/2$](v4)(v6);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\stackinset{c}{7cm}{c}{}{\rotatebox{90}{\dashline{2in}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-4.6cm}{c}{-1.5cm}{\rotatebox{-38}{\dashline{3.2in}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{1cm}{\dashline{6in}}{%
\mygraph}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]