# How can I draw a curved cut line in a DAG?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, technical-drawing

Here I have drawed a DAG(s). If possible I want to cut it with a curved lined.

My code:

```tex
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows, decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [vertex/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white},
        node distance=2cm,
        on grid,
        >=latex
        ]
        % \draw[gray!50] (-1,-2) grid (5,2);
        \node[vertex] (A) {$J5$};
        \node[vertex,above left=1cm and 1cm of A] (B) {$J4$};
        \node[vertex,below=of B] (C) {$J3$};
        \node[vertex,left=of A] (D) {$J2$};
        \node[vertex,left=of D] (F) {$J1$};
        \draw[->]
        (C) edge (A)
        (B) edge (A)
        (D) edge (C)
        (D) edge (B)
        (F) edge (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Wanted output:

| Example-1 | Example-2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Related: [how to draw a cut through a graph in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170040/how-to-draw-a-cut-through-a-graph-in-latex)

Comment: Does the line need to be so random? Is a varying line width really neded? Or can it be just a normal line/curve?

Comment: Yes sir, It can be just a normal curve line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to find the start and end points of your cuts somehow.
Here I'm just using the [intersections of perpendicular lines](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.3.1) through your nodes.

One cut is just a straight line, the other one is a curve around J2 which is done via [`bend left`](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#tikz/bend:left) and a [`min distance`](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#tikz/min:distance).

I'll provide two `cut line` styles: one uses the `random steps` decoration, the one is just a dashed line.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, positioning, arrows.meta, angles}
\tikzset{
  cut line/.style={
    rounded corners=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,
    decoration={name=random steps}, decorate},
%  cut line/.style=dashed,
}
\pgfmathsetseed{693069} % reproducable output
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[!htp]
%    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vertex/.style={circle, draw=black}, node distance=2cm, on grid, >=Latex]
\node[vertex]                               (J5) {$J5$};
\node[vertex, above left=1cm and 1cm of J5] (J4) {$J4$};
\node[vertex, below=of J4]                  (J3) {$J3$};
\node[vertex, left=of J5]                   (J2) {$J2$};
\node[vertex, left=of J2]                   (J1) {$J1$};
\path[->] (J1) edge (J2) (J2) edge (J4) edge (J3) (J4) edge (J5) (J3) edge (J5);
\draw[red, cut line] (J2|-J4) -- (J5|-J3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vertex/.style={circle, draw=black}, node distance=2cm, on grid, >=Latex]
\node[vertex]                               (J5) {$J5$};
\node[vertex, above left=1cm and 1cm of J5] (J4) {$J4$};
\node[vertex, below=of J4]                  (J3) {$J3$};
\node[vertex, left=of J5]                   (J2) {$J2$};
\node[vertex, left=of J2]                   (J1) {$J1$};
\path[->] (J1) edge (J2) (J2) edge (J4) edge (J3) (J4) edge (J5) (J3) edge (J5);
\draw[red, cut line] (J2|-J4) to[bend left=45, min distance=1.2cm] (J2|-J3);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### `random steps`

[image]
[image]

#### `dashed`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to sligthly shift the drawn line in y-axis? In the cases of if I have a label in the center, the line overwrites it

Comment: @alper You can always adjst the position with a transformation, say `\draw[red, cut line] ([xshift=4mm]J2|-J4) -- ([yshift=4mm]J5|-J3);`