# Drawing minimal xy axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, pstricks, metapost

can anybody help me to draw this minimal example of an xy axis? I couldn't find anything similar on the forum.

The axis should be black but the grid behind it a shade o gray, dashed. It would be great if the axis were a little bit thicker than the grid also.

[image: Axis]

Comment: Have a look at chapter 2 of the [TikZ manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (first tutorial).

Comment: A minimal xy axis is great and useful, but maybe next month you need something more specific. ;-) So think of that when you choose one of the answers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant @Arne, but thank you for the contribution. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe, later you will add functions, or willing to controle the numbers on the x or y axe, or make it discontinue ... (for good practice of the forum just click the up arrow instead of typing thanks ;-) It is the way it goes here.

Comment: @PierPaolo Sir, the link to the tutorial has expired. Could you please update it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

with `TiKZ`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal Axis]

Comment: That's great Ignasi. I would do a slight modification, to do the dashed lines. Thank you!

Comment: @bru1987 Glad to help you. Add `dashed` after `help lines` and the grid will be built with dashed lines.

Comment: Thank you @Ignasi, I just did that, along with making it a lighter black. I hope you like the modification. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the option of Triangle-Triangle within the \draw command to have better arrows.  You will need to load the arrow package in the usetikzlibrary.

Answer (score 41):

Why `pgfplots` is left out?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both,ymin=-5,ymax=5,xmax=5,xmin=-5,xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
               minor tick num=1,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,label style =
               {at={(ticklabel cs:1.1)}}]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Honestly, I didn't think of this possibility. But now that we are rolling, you could mention of adding `axis equal=true` to have the same scale in both axes.

Answer (score 17):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

% parameter
\def\size{5} % natural number

\begin{pspicture}(-\size,-\size)(\size.57,\size.62)% found manually
  \multido{\iA = -\size+1}{\numexpr2*\size+1}{%
    \multido{\iB = -\size+1}{\numexpr2*\size+1}{%
    \psset{linewidth = 0.5\pslinewidth, linestyle = dashed, linecolor = gray!50}
      \psline(-\size,\iA)(\size,\iA)
      \psline(\iB,-\size)(\iB,\size)}}
  \psaxes[labels = none]{->}(0,0)(-\size,-\size)(\size.21,\size.21)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the value of `\size` and the drawing will be adjusted accordingly.

I've drawn the grid manually since [`pstricks-add`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add)'s function for this makes it look wierd, I think.

Comment: Hi Svend, that's a great looking image. How could I remove the number labels on it, keeping the spacing between them? Thank you!

Comment: @bru1987 See updated answer.

Comment: That's a great solution @Svend, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 17):

And here is a fairly generic [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) approach to making a grid.  Follow the link for an introduction to Metapost and how to use this code in a LaTeX document.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

u = 1cm;
ymax = xmax = 4.75;
xmin = ymin = -4.75;

path xx, yy;
xx = ((xmin,0) -- (xmax,0)) scaled u;
yy = ((0,ymin) -- (0,ymax)) scaled u;

drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled .5 withcolor .7 white);
for i = ceiling ymin upto floor ymax: draw xx shifted (0,i*u); endfor
for i = ceiling xmin upto floor xmax: draw yy shifted (i*u,0); endfor

drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled .7);
xx := xx scaled 1.05;
yy := yy scaled 1.05;
drawarrow xx;
drawarrow yy;
drawoptions();

label.rt (btex $x$ etex, point infinity of xx);
label.top(btex $y$ etex, point infinity of yy);

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Having never worked with Metapost myself, I may ask a (maybe silly) question: how do I incorporate this code in my LaTeX document?

Comment: Not silly at all - if you follow the link at the top of my answer, that should get you going.

Answer (score 17):

Just a simple way, easy to adapt, (but the lines or not dashed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5]
\tkzGrid[sub,color=gray, subxstep=.5,subystep=.5]
\tkzAxeXY[very thick]
\tkzGrid
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tkz-euclide` I think is underappreciated. it is always my go to tikz-based package for quick plots.

Answer (score 16):

A stack was too much to resist, so onto the bandwagon I jump.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,amssymb}
\setstackgap{L}{1cm}
\def\stacktype{L}
% DASHED LINE OF SPECIFIED LENGTH
% From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
% how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\solidfill{\cleaders\hbox to .1cm{\rule{.1cm}{1pt}}\hfill}
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .2cm{\rule{.05cm}{.4pt}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}
\newcommand\solidline[1]{\hbox to #1{\solidfill\hfil}}
\newcommand\DL{\textcolor{black!30}{\dashline{8.6cm}}}
\newcommand\SL{\textcolor{black}{\solidline{8.8cm}}\makebox[.2cm][r]{\arrowhead}}
\def\arrowhead{\raisebox{-2.6pt}{$\blacktriangleright$}}
\begin{document}
\savestack\partA{\Longstack{\DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \SL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL}}
\stackinset{c}{10pt}{t}{3pt}{$y$}{%
  \stackinset{r}{3pt}{c}{-10pt}{$x$}{%
    \stackon[-.5cm]{\partA}{\rotatebox{90}{\partA}}%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

No graphics question is complete without a `picture` mode solution:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\unitlength=1cm

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(10.5,10.5)(-5,-5)
  {\color{gray}
  \thinlines
  \multiput(-5,-4)(0,1){9}{\line(1,0){10}}
  \multiput(-4,-5)(1,0){9}{\line(0,1){10}}
  }
  \thicklines
  \put(-5,0){\vector(1,0){10.2}}
  \put(0,-5){\vector(0,1){10.2}}
  \put(5.3,0){\makebox(1,0)[l]{$x$}}
  \put(0,5.3){\makebox(0,1)[b]{$y$}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a pitty, that I only can add +1 to your counter.  You are so right :-)  This would also be my answer.

Answer (score 13):

My own try with MetaPost, which is integrated into a LuaLaTeX program. I've picked up some macros I had already created for my own use (and modified some of them slightly).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex;

    def hgrid(expr ymin, ymax, ystep, u, v)(text mycolor) =
      for j = ceiling(ymin) step ystep until floor(ymax):
        draw ((xmin, j) -- (xmax, j)) xscaled u yscaled v withcolor mycolor;
      endfor;
    enddef;

    def vgrid(expr xmin, xmax, xstep, u, v)(text mycolor) =
      for i = ceiling(xmin) step xstep until floor(xmax):
        draw ((i, ymin) -- (i, ymax)) xscaled u yscaled v withcolor mycolor;
      endfor;
    enddef;

    vardef xaxis(expr xmin, xmax, u) = ((xmin, 0) -- (xmax, 0)) scaled u enddef;
    vardef yaxis(expr ymin, ymax, v) = ((0, ymin) -- (0, ymax)) scaled v enddef;

    beginfig(1);}
  \everyendmplib{endfig;}

\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u := 1cm; v := 1.25cm;
    xmin = -4.9; xmax = 4.9; ymin = -4.5; ymax = 4.5;
    vgrid(xmin, xmax, 1, u, v, 0.8white dashed evenly); 
    hgrid(ymin, ymax, 1, u, v, 0.8white dashed evenly);
    pickup pencircle scaled 1bp;
    drawarrow xaxis(xmin, xmax, u); drawarrow yaxis(ymin, ymax, v);
    label.bot(btex $x$ etex, (xmax*u, 0)); label.lft(btex $y$ etex, (0, ymax*v));
 \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Result as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This time with the `mfpic` package, which is a (La)TeX interface to MetaPost or Metafont (here used MetaPost). Note that this program is shorter than my correponding MetaPost coding, since `mfpic` already has its own drawing macros.

In exchange it requires several compilations, à la bibTeX: first compile your LaTeX file, say `grid.tex`, with LaTeX, then the created `grid.mp` file with MetaPost, and then again `grid.tex` with LaTeX. As a regular `mfpic` user I use a script which automatizes this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
  \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
\opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mfpic}[1]{-4.9}{4.9}{-4.5}{4.5}
    \drawcolor[gray]{0.8}
    \begin{mfpfor}{i = ceiling(\xmin) step 1 until floor(\xmax)}
      \dashed\lines{(i, \ymin), (i, \ymax)}
    \end{mfpfor}
    \begin{mfpfor}{j = ceiling(\ymin) step 1 until floor(\ymax)}
       \dashed\lines{(\xmin, j), (\xmax, j)}
    \end{mfpfor}
    \drawcolor{black}
    \penwd{1bp}
    \doaxes{xy}
    \tlpointsep{3bp}
    \tlabels{[tc](\xmax, 0){$x$} [cr](0, \ymax){$y$}}
  \end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5.4,-5.4)(5.4,5.4)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticklinestyle=dashed,ticksize=-5 5,
        tickcolor=black!20](0,0)(-5,-5)(5,5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-5,-5)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative MWE with PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
 \begin{document}
   \begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=darkgray]
\psaxes[linewidth=1.2pt, labels=all]{->}(0,0)(-5,-5)(5,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,-180]
   \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not use the `minimal` class for examples. It is not suitable.

Comment: I made the change by following your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{figure[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture]\draw[step=0.5cm,opacity=0.5] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[below right]{$x$};
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,ultra thick] (0,5) node[above left]{$y$}--(0,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```