# Drawing simple xy axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

Can anybody help me to produce this? I couldn't find anything similar on the forum. 
No need for a grid.

[image]

Thank you,

Mironas

Comment: If you don't need a grid, use a white paper sheet instead. ;)

Comment: An almost exact same question is on the right, under "Related": [Drawing minimal xy axis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222882/drawing-minimal-xy-axis?rq=1)

Comment: @HerrK. The line was the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(6,5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(6,5)
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic,yMaxValue=4.5]{0.1}{5.5}{1/x}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With some colour (and names):

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2.5,-2)(5,4)
\psset{algebraic, arrowinset=0.125, arrowsize=3pt, linejoin=1}
\psaxes[linecolor=OrangeRed2!80, ticks=none, labels=none, arrows=-](0,0)(-2.5,-2)(5,4) [$x$,-135] [$y$,-135]
\uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=DarkOliveGreen3, plotpoints=100, plotstyle=curve}
\psplot{0.255}{4.85}{1/x}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]