# Connect multiple plots in one picture

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to create something like in this picture (done in PowerPoint) with TikZ/pgfplots.
I would be really happy if someone knows of an example that I could use for inspiration!

Thanks a lot!

[image: Graph plot]

Comment: The three axis should basically be the same size, but shifted into the "depth"/z direction.

Comment: I would suggest putting each axis environment in a scope and using xshift and yshift to move their respective origins.  The dashed line would be drawn outside the scopes using previously defined coordinate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of my answer is setup for this particular MWE, since the OP provided no graphs to be overlaid... I had to create my own.

After spending most of the code building a green, blue, and red graph as placeholders (they could be something with `tikz` instead), I then use `\stackinset` to lay them up relative to each other and to overlay some dashed orange lines.

Here is the MWE.  Look to the end for the nested `\stackinset`s that actually accomplish the graph.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,amssymb}
\begin{document}
%%%%% THE FOLLOWING IS ME DEFINING THREE GRAPHS; YOUR CODE WILL BE DIFFERENT
\setstackgap{L}{.5cm}
\def\stacktype{L}
% DASHED LINE OF SPECIFIED LENGTH
% From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
% how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\solidfill{\cleaders\hbox to .1cm{\rule{.1cm}{1pt}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashfill[1][.4pt]{\cleaders\hbox to .2cm{\rule{.05cm}{#1}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[2][.4pt]{\hbox to #2{\dashfill[#1]\hfil}}
\newcommand\solidline[1]{\hbox to #1{\solidfill\hfil}}
\newcommand\DL{\textcolor{black!30}{\dashline{4.3cm}}}
\newcommand\SL{\solidline{4.4cm}\makebox[.2cm][r]{\arrowhead}}
\def\arrowhead{\raisebox{-2.6pt}{$\blacktriangleright$}}
\savestack\partblue{\color{blue}\Longstack{\SL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL}}
\savestack\partred{\color{red}\Longstack{\SL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL}}
\savestack\partgreen{\color{green}\Longstack{\SL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL\\ \DL}}
\def\basegrid#1{\color{#1}%
\stackinset{l}{15pt}{t}{3pt}{$y$}{%
  \stackinset{r}{0pt}{b}{12pt}{$x$}{%
    \stackon[-.5cm]{\raisebox{7.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{%
    \csname part#1\endcsname}}}{\rotatebox{90}{\csname part#1\endcsname}}%
}}}
\savestack\gridblue{\basegrid{blue}}
\savestack\gridred{\basegrid{red}}
\savestack\gridgreen{\basegrid{green}}
%%%%%

%%%%% HERE IS WHERE I OVERLAY THE THREE GRAPHS
%%%%% NOTE: \Lstackgap IS THE SPACING BETWEEN DASHED GRID RULES

% ORANGE DASHES
\stackinset{l}{9.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{b}{2.1\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\rotatebox{-115}{%
  \color{orange!90!black}\dashline[2pt]{2.7\dimexpr\Lstackgap}}}{%
\stackinset{l}{3.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{b}{0.1\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\rotatebox{-115}{%
  \color{orange!90!black}\dashline[2pt]{2.7\dimexpr\Lstackgap}}}{%
% OVER STAGGERED GRID
\stackinset{l}{10\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{b}{4\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\gridred}{%
\stackinset{l}{4\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{b}{2\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\gridblue}{\gridgreen}}%
}}


\end{document}
```

[image]